# Non-resolvable parent POM issue

Tags: maven, parent-pom

issue:

```
[ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.name.dept:comp:5.0.15-SNAPSHOT-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact com.name.dept:comp-parent:pom:1.0.12 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 3, column 10
```

my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.comp.dept.proj</groupId>
    <artifactId>proj-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.12</version>
    // Not recongized
    <relativePath>/proj-parent-1.0.12.pom</relativePath>
</parent>
<artifactId>mycomp</artifactId>
<version>5.0.15-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>CompName</name>

below is the parent pom
-------------
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.comp.dept.proj</groupId>
<artifactId>proj-parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0.12</version>
<name>Parent</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
```

My parent file name is dept-parent-1.0.12.pom.  What setting of Maven or IntelliJ would solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your parent's groupId seems wrong (ending with :comp - maybe pasted stuff?). Start trying with

```
<groupId>com.name.dept</groupId>
```

Comment: Sorry it was my bad, it is there like you mentioned only.

Comment: Can you show us your parent pom ? Your version numbers are different between parent version et filename.

Comment: Also your parent filename is really strange: a POM file should be named pom.xml.
Parent's filename mentions version 1.1.12 but you specify 1.0.16 in your current pom. Are you sure about the version ?

Comment: corrected everything, could you please see it now @lohnns

Comment: I think it is because of some setting as pom is working fine when I work in the non-cloud environments..

Comment: one more observation when I used eclipse was I see the below error: Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.comp.dept.proj:translator:versionnumber-SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer com.comp.dept.proj:comp:proj-parent:pom:1.0.12 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.

Comment: Looking at the update, can you confirm me your parent file named 'proj-parent-1.0.12.pom' is in the same directory than your actual pom ?
How do you build your project ?

Comment: parent pom is in the .m2 directory, I use intellij to build this.

Comment: If your parent artifact (so is your parent pom), you don't need to specify the location of the pom. When you mention an artifact in a POM file, Maven will try to get it from your repository.
I think you did something wrong with your parent location.
If parent is part of your own code, then you should refer to its pom.xml (I don't understand why you make a copy of it in your current folder). Try to point to the real pom of your parent (in its own directory?)

Comment: you mean relativepath? I mentioned this because it is not finding the location, even if it is not there it is not working.. I see it as a http/https connection issue or some IDE setup issue as it was working before.

Comment: If you own the parent code and you have a copy of the artifact in your local repository (.m2), there is no reason to have a connection issue.
Try to build your project from command line if you think IDE are in cause.
Run mvn clean install -U to force maven to update dependencies and see the result.

Comment: unfortunately I see the same issue.